# ¿Cómo hago para imprimir en html mi tabla de MySQL que carga muchos datos?

Tags: mysql, html5, python-3.x, flask

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver hay un dato que cambia de donde dice *"pedro"* a donde dice *"juan"*, los demas son los mismos datos, pero quiero imprmir a *"pedro"* y a *"juan"* en `html`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y ahí es donde lo imprimo, pero no sé como hacerle para que salga tambien *"juan"*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así es como se ve en mi página web. Bueno también cabe aclarar que lo estoy haciendo con `flask`.

Si alguien me pudiera ayudar, muchas gracias.

```
    <form action="/user/{{contact.0}}" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
      <table class="egt" cellspacing ="10px" id="tabla">
        <tbody id="obj4.1"  style="display: none;">
            <tr><td><div class="form-group" style="display: none;"><input type="text" name="id_cliente" placeholder="r_id" class="form-control" value="{{contact.16}}"></div></td></tr>
          <tr>
            <td><div class="form-group"><input type="text" name="nom_contact" placeholder="Nombre del Contacto" class="form-control" style="width: 500 px;"></div></td>
            <td><div class="form-group"><input type="text" name="telefono" placeholder="Telefono" class="form-control" style="width: 700 px;"></div></td>
            <td><div class="form-group"><input type="text" name="correo" placeholder="Correo" class="form-control"></div></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><div class="form-group"><input type="text" name="nom_contact2" placeholder="Nombre del Contacto" class="form-control" style="width: 500 px;"></div></td>
            <td><div class="form-group"><input type="text" name="telefono2" placeholder="Telefono" class="form-control" style="width: 700 px;"></div></td>
            <td><div class="form-group"><input type="text" name="correo2" placeholder="Correo" class="form-control"></div></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><div class="form-group"><input type="text" name="nom_contact3" placeholder="Nombre del Contacto" class="form-control" style="width: 500 px;"></div></td>
            <td><div class="form-group"><input type="text" name="telefono3" placeholder="Telefono" class="form-control" style="width: 700 px;"></div></td>
            <td><div class="form-group"><input type="text" name="correo3" placeholder="Correo" class="form-control"></div></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><div class="form-group"><input type="text" name="nom_contact4" placeholder="Nombre del Contacto" class="form-control" style="width: 500 px;"></div></td>
            <td><div class="form-group"><input type="text" name="telefono4" placeholder="Telefono" class="form-control" style="width: 700 px;"></div></td>
            <td><div class="form-group"><input type="text" name="correo4" placeholder="Correo" class="form-control"></div></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><div class="form-group"><input type="text" name="nom_contact5" placeholder="Nombre del Contacto" class="form-control" style="width: 500 px;"></div></td>
            <td><div class="form-group"><input type="text" name="telefono5" placeholder="Telefono" class="form-control" style="width: 700 px;"></div></td>
            <td><div class="form-group"><input type="text" name="correo5" placeholder="Correo" class="form-control"></div></td>
          </tr>
          <tr><td><button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit"  name="submit_button" value="Contact">Guardar</button></td></tr>
        </tbody>
        <table id="obj4.2" style="display: block;" cellspacing ="10px">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <td>Nombre</td>
              <td></td>
              <td>Telefono</td>
              <td></td>
              <td>Correo electronico</td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>{{ contact.22}}</td>
                <td></td>
                <td>{{ contact.23}}</td>
                <td></td> 
                <td>{{ contact.24}}</td>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                  <a href="/edit/{{contact.0}}"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a>
                  <a href="/delete/{{contact.0}}"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
                </td>
              </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </table>
    </form>
```

Así es como tengo el código de `html` por que en otro div pido los datos para llenarnos.

```py
@app.route('/user/<id>', methods =['GET','POST'])
def user(id):
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    cur.execute('SELECT * FROM cliente INNER JOIN credit ON cliente.r_id = credit.id_cliente INNER JOIN contacts ON cliente.r_id = contacts.id_cliente INNER JOIN campus ON cliente.r_id = campus.id_cliente INNER JOIN ordenes ON cliente.r_id = ordenes.id_cliente WHERE cliente.id = {0} '.format(id))
    data = cur.fetchall()
    print(data)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['submit_button'] == 'Guardar':
            rfc = request.form['RFC']
            razon = request.form['razon_social']
            cp = request.form['cp']
            calle = request.form['calle']
            ext = request.form['ext']
            intn = request.form['intn']
            colonia = request.form['colonia']
            estfac = request.form['estfac']
            municipio = request.form['municipio']
            cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
            cur.execute("""
            UPDATE cliente
            SET RFC = %s,
                razon_social = %s,
                cp = %s,
                calle = %s,
                ext = %s,
                intn = %s,
                colonia = %s,
                estfac = %s,
                municipio = %s
            WHERE id = %s
        """, (rfc, razon, cp, calle, ext, intn, colonia, estfac, municipio, id))
            mysql.connection.commit() 
            return render_template('user.html', contact = data[0])
        elif request.form['submit_button'] == 'Tarjeta':
            tarjeta = request.form['numtarj']
            fecha = request.form['fecha']
            nombre = request.form['nombre']
            cv = request.form['cv']
            id_cliente = request.form['id_cliente']
            cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
            cur.execute('INSERT INTO credit(numtarj, fecha, nombre, cv, id_cliente) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)',(tarjeta, fecha, nombre, cv, id_cliente))
            cur.execute('DELETE FROM credit WHERE nombre = " "')
            mysql.connection.commit() 
            return render_template('user.html', contact = data[0])
        if request.form['submit_button'] == 'Contact':
            contacto = request.form['nom_contact']
            telefono = request.form['telefono']
            correo = request.form['correo']
            id_cliente = request.form['id_cliente']
            contacto2 = request.form['nom_contact2']
            telefono2 = request.form['telefono2']
            correo2 = request.form['correo2']
            contacto3 = request.form['nom_contact3']
            telefono3 = request.form['telefono3']
            correo3 = request.form['correo3']
            contacto4 = request.form['nom_contact4']
            telefono4 = request.form['telefono4']
            correo4 = request.form['correo4']
            contacto5 = request.form['nom_contact5']
            telefono5 = request.form['telefono5']
            correo5 = request.form['correo5']
            data = [(contacto,telefono, correo, id_cliente),(contacto2 ,telefono2, correo2, id_cliente),(contacto3,telefono3, correo3, id_cliente),(contacto4,telefono4, correo4, id_cliente),(contacto5,telefono5, correo5, id_cliente)]
            cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
            sql = "INSERT INTO contacts (nom_contact, telefono,correo, id_cliente) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)"
            cur.executemany(sql,data)
            cur.execute('DELETE FROM contacts WHERE nom_contact = " "')
            mysql.connection.commit() 
            return render_template('user.html', contact = data[0])
        if request.form['submit_button'] == 'Campus':
            campus = request.form['Campus']
            direccion = request.form['direccion']
            id_cliente = request.form['id_cliente']
            cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
            cur.execute("INSERT INTO campus(Campus,direccion, id_cliente) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", (campus, direccion, id_cliente))
            cur.execute('DELETE FROM Campus WHERE campus = " "')
            mysql.connection.commit() 
            return render_template('user.html', contact = data[0])
        if request.form['submit_button'] == 'Orden':
            emisor = request.form['emisor']
            marca = request.form['marca']
            fecha = request.form['fecha']
            campus = request.form['campus']
            servicio = request.form['servicio']
            precio = request.form['precio']
            cantidad = request.form['cantidad']
            id_cliente = request.form['id_cliente']
            valores = (emisor, marca, fecha, campus, servicio, precio, cantidad, id_cliente)
            cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
            sql = "INSERT INTO ordenes (emisor, marca, fecha, campus, servicio, precio, cantidad, id_cliente) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
            cur.execute(sql,valores)
            cur.execute('DELETE FROM ordenes WHERE marca = " "')
            mysql.connection.commit() 
            return render_template('user.html', contact = data[0])
    return render_template('user.html',contact = data[0])
```

Y todo eso es mi Python en donde lleno los datos a mi base, y borro algunas otras cosas.

Si saben una manera de simplificar tanto código tambien estaría super bien, gracias.

Comment: Hola, podrías poner el fragmento de código real en vez de una foto, ayudará a los que deseen ayudarte.

Comment: si claro ahortia lo pongo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

para lograr lo que quieres podrías enviar la colección completa y con un ciclo iterar por ella mostrando los elementos. Algo como esto:

```html
<table id="obj4.2" style="display: block;" cellspacing="10px">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Nombre</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>Teléfono</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>Correo electrónico</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>Opciones</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for contacto in contacts %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ contacto.22 }}</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>{{ contacto.23 }}</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>{{ contacto.24 }}</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <a href="/edit/{{contacto.0}}"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a>
                <a href="/delete/{{contacto.0}}"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Puedes agregar el objeto contacts (data) junto a contact(data[0]) de la siguiente forma:

```py
return render_template('user.html', contact = data[0], contacts = data)
```

**Nota**: El ciclo en el código html fue modificado.

Comment: muchas gracias pero al hacer eso me imprime a pedro varias veces

Comment: He actualizado la respuesta para incluir los datos de todos los contactos que resultan de la consulta que ejecutas junto al contacto específico que tienes. En resumen, se trabaja con dos variables: `contact` y `contacts`.

Comment: Gracias serias tan amable de explicarme el por que ?

Comment: Qué explicación necesitas? Si te funcionó (espero), supongo que preguntas por qué funciona: en  ese caso respondo: la función `render_template` envía a la web los datos `contact` que posee la información del usuario actual (data[0]) y `contacts` que posee todo el resultado de la consulta (data). En la web muestras datos específicos con `contact` y en el ciclo, los datos de los contactos que están en `contacts`. Se entiende?

Comment: Ohhhhhh muchas gracias si me sirvio y de verdad te lo agradezco muchisimas gracias